# How to apply style class to all input element in a form using Mootools

Tags: css, mootools

How to apply common style class to all input element in a form using Mootools.
Thanks

Comment: http://mootools.net/docs/core

Answer (score 5):

`document.id('your-form-id').getElements('input').addClass('someClass');`

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ZQGVK/

Answer (score -1):

For jQuery use:

```
$('#your-form-id :input).addClass('someClass')
```